# Empty cell Typo3 Fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid

Trying to set up a query for the "address list-Plugin" in Typo3.
So if my cell "Title" is written to there would be some information like "Prof.Dr." but if there's no Title on the Entry there should be "-"

Got no code at all at this point because its totally new to me but i assume it would like this a bit:

`f:if condition{empty.cell} -` or something. Never worked with it till yesterday and can't find any documentation that's helpful about my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An introduction to FLUID could be found [here](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/Fluid/Index.html#fluid)

A special hint for beginners:
If you want to know which FLUID variables are defined you can use of the `f:debug` Viewhelper:

```html
<f:debug title="info at ...">{_all}</f:debug>
```

---

The exact syntax for your usage would be:

```html
<f:if condition="{address.title}">
  <f:then>{address.title}</f:then>
  <f:else>-</f:else>
</f:if>
```